# How should I configure HTTPS rstudio-server and shiny server on nginx reverse proxy on raspberry pi

Tags: nginx, https, shiny-server, rstudio-server, shinyapps

***What I want to do --***

I have running Rstudio and Shiny server on my raspberry pi accessible on http://"my.public.ip":8787 and: 3838 port. I want to tie both the server through Nginx to my domain, e.g., "https://code.example.blog/rstudio" and similarly for shiny-server .../shiny-admin.
Domain code.example.blog is purchased from Wordpress and points to my public IP.

***My references --***

I am a noob I went through the information available on google and used these two sites as reference
— https://ttdtrang.tk/2019/04/configure-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-rstudio-server/ 
— https://gist.github.com/magic-lanter/1b5e11c3cf5964b69e8e7824df015c5d

***What I did--***

1. I created  rstudio_shiny.conf block and placed it at this location, "etc/nginx/conf.d/rstudio_shiny.conf"
2. Added these lines to "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"  http { map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade { default upgrade; ''      close;}

***What is happening --***

1. Browsing "https://code.example.blog" takes me to nginx welcome
   page and there is no change is displayed address
2. Browsing "https://code.example.blog/rstudio"  redirects to
   **http:**//"my.public.ip":8787

***This behavior should change to  --***

- need to use **https** instead of http
- the address should stay as "https://code.example.blog/rstudio" instead of displaying  my public ip (low priority)

> Can you please a have look at block below and suggest a solution also could you advise me if this config will allow me to host shiny app?

**My network--**

Static IP with 80,443,22,8787,3838 as open port

**

> etc/nginx/conf.d/rstudio_shiny.conf
>   **

```
server {     

if ($host = code.example.blog) {     
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;  
   } # managed by Certbot    
listen 80 ;   
listen [::]:80 ;     
server_name code.example.blog;   

}    



server {     
   access_log /var/log/nginx/code.example.blog;  
   root /var/www/html;   
   index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;   
   listen 443 ssl default_server;    
   listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;  

 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/code.example.blog/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot     
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/code.example.blog/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot   
 include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot   
 ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot     
 server_name code.example.blog;  

location /rstudio/ {     
 rewrite ^/rstudio/(.*)$ /$1 break;  
 proxy_pass http://MY.PUB.IP:8787;   
 proxy_redirect http://MY.PUB.IP:8787/ $scheme://$host/rstudio/;      
 proxy_http_version 1.1;     
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;     
 proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;    
 proxy_read_timeout 20d;     
}    

location /shiny-admin/ {      
 rewrite ^/shiny-admin/(.*)$ /$1 break;  
 proxy_pass http://MY.PUB.IP:3838;   
 proxy_redirect http://MY.PUB.IP:8787/ $scheme://$http_host/shiny-admin/;    
 proxy_http_version 1.1;     
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;     
 proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;    
 proxy_read_timeout 20d;     
 proxy_buffering off;    

}    
}
```

Comment: I solved this by replacing "MY.PUB.IP" with domain name " code.example.blog"  I am not going to remove it I will keep it as reference for other noobs like myself